# lazy loading static list of select options for performance

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2, selectize.js

I hit into this problem today, where I have more than 1000 options in my dropdown list, and although it is coming from the database, it is stored in a single column, (we don't want to change the database schema for it). Right now those options are displaying in the select2 field.

**Problem**

- If there are these many options there can be more than 1000 options though, then we are hitting performance issues, as well as, UI becomes non-responsive for some time.

**Question**

Can we handle this with lazy loading? Is there a way to lazy load a static list of options may be using javascript or select2? Again I know there is an Ajax option for select2, but as I explained earlier, all of those 1000+ options are stored in one database column as a static string

**UPDATE**

Turns out, those 6000+ options were actually stored as postgresql array field, which is causing performance issue with Rails framework.

Comment: the main question is that will your user scroll to select from these 1000 options. I guess not. you may want to consider providing a search to assist them in choosing these options. just my 2 cents worth.

Comment: @D.Seah You are right, so there already is a search box in select2 at the moment, but those options are like static list of options at the moment. My question is, how to improve performance and load those options in efficient way even in Select2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use check the [select2 ajax](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) method, it will help a lot you when there are so many records in options.